# Split, Math.max не работают

Tags: javascript

И то и другое не работает, почему?

```js
    let x = [5,4,2]
    
    console.log(x.split(""))
    console.log(Math.max(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то такое хотели?

```js
let x = [5,4,2]
    
console.log(x.join("").split(""))
console.log(Math.max.apply(null,x))

console.log(Math.max(...x))
```

Кусочек [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

> Нахождение максимального элемента в массиве Следующая функция
> использует метод Function.prototype.apply() для нахождения
> максимального элемента в числовом массиве. Вызов getMaxOfArray([1, 2,
> 3]) эквивалентен вызову Math.max(1, 2, 3),

Comment: да, но а без apply нельзя?

Comment: Мах не принимает массив просто. Из-за этого и применяется apply который как раз таки принимает.